Subgroup of the braid group $\mathbb{B}_n$ generated by $\sigma_1,\dots,\sigma_{n-2},\sigma_{n-1}^2$
I want to prove the following.
Let $\mathbb{B}_n:=
\left\langle
\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_{n-1}
\mid 
[\sigma_i,\sigma_{j}]=1,\ j-i>1,\ 
\sigma_i\cdot\sigma_{i+1}\cdot\sigma_i=
\sigma_{i+1}\cdot\sigma_i\cdot\sigma_{i+1}
\right\rangle$ be the braid group on $n$ strands. There is a natural homomorphism $S:\mathbb{B}_n \to \Sigma_n$ where $\Sigma_n$ is the symmetric group and $S$ is the permutation that the braid induces in its ends. Let $\mathfrak{S}_n\subset\Sigma_n$ be the stabilizer of $n$ and $\mathbb{S}_n:=S^{-1}(\mathfrak{S}_n) $. This is the set of braids whose $n$-th string does not permute the ends.
I know that $\mathbb{S}_n$ is generated by $\sigma_1,\dots,\sigma_{n-2},\sigma_{n-1}^2$, but I don't know how to prove it. I think I could do it by induction but the step of induction is driving me crazy.
Anyone knows how to do it or any reference to a not very complicated proof? I have seen some involving trivial fibrations but that is too much.
Thanks!
I have come up with the following proof, but it is incomplete. If someone knows how to continue I'll be very grateful. This is the proof:
To begin with, we have $S(\sigma_i) = (i, i+1)$ for all $i = 1, \dots, n-2$ and $S(\sigma_{n-1}^2) = \mathbf{1}$, therefore, these braids belong to $\mathbb{S}_n$. We will prove this by induction on $n$.
For $n=1$, we have $\mathbb{S}_n = \mathbb{B}_n = \{\mathbf{1}\}$, so it is trivial. For $n=2$, $\mathbb{B}_2 = \langle \sigma_1 \rangle$ and on the other hand $\sigma_1^2 \in \mathbb{S}_2$ but $\sigma_1 \notin \mathbb{S}_2$, so $\mathbb{S}_2 = \langle \sigma_1^2 \rangle$ and the statement is true.
Assume that the statement is true for all $m < n$. Given $\tau \in \mathbb{S}_n$, we denote by $\#\sigma_i^{\pm1}(\tau)$ the number of $\sigma_i^{\pm1}$ elements in the reduced word $\tau$. We now apply another induction on $\#\sigma_i^{\pm1}(\tau)$.

If $\#\sigma_{n-1}^{\pm1}(\tau) = 0$, then $\tau$ is trivially a product of the generators in the statement.

If $\#\sigma_{n-1}(\tau) = 1$, it is a contradiction, since $\sigma_{n-1}^{\pm}$ cannot appear only once in $\tau$.

If $\#\sigma_{n-1}^{\pm1}(\tau) = 2$, then multiplying $\tau$ on the left or right by $\sigma_i, \: i \neq n-1$ or by $\sigma_{n-1}^2$, we obtain that $\tau$ is a product of the generators in the statement if and only if the braid $\sigma_{n-1} \alpha \sigma_{n-1}^{-1}$ is, where $\alpha$ is a word in which $\sigma_{n-1}^{\pm1}$ does not appear. Therefore, by removing the last straight strand, we can assume that $\alpha \in \mathbb{B}_{n-1}$. It is immediate to check that $\alpha \in \mathbb{S}_{n-1}$. By induction, $\alpha$ is a word written as a product of $\sigma_1, \dots, \sigma_{n-3}, \sigma_{n-2}^2$, which we write as $\alpha = w(\sigma_1, \dots, \sigma_{n-3}, \sigma_{n-2}^2)$.


Given that conjugation by an element is a group isomorphism, we have:
$$
\sigma_{n-1} \alpha \sigma_{n-1}^{-1} = w(\sigma_{n-1} \sigma_1 \sigma_{n-1}^{-1}, \dots, \sigma_{n-1} \sigma_{n-3} \sigma_{n-1}^{-1}, \sigma_{n-1} \sigma_{n-2}^2 \sigma_{n-1}^{-1}) = w(\sigma_1, \dots, \sigma_3, \sigma_{n-2}^{-1} \sigma_{n-1}^2 \sigma_{n-2}),
$$
where we use that $\sigma_{n-1} \sigma_{n-2}^2 \sigma_{n-1}^{-1}= \sigma_{n-2}^{-1} \sigma_{n-1}^2 \sigma_{n-2}$. Thus, the statement holds.
We assume the statement is true for all $m<n$ and for any braid $\tau \in \mathbb{S}_n$ with $\#\sigma_{n-1}^{\pm1}(\tau) < k$. Given a braid $\tau \in \mathbb{S}_n$ with $\sigma_{n-1}^{\pm1}(\tau) = k$, multiplying it on the left and right by $\sigma_i \, i \neq n-1$ if necessary, we obtain that $\tau$ is a product of the desired generators if and only if the word $\sigma_{n-1} \alpha \sigma_{n-1}^{-1}$ is a product oh these generators.
I don't really know how to continue. We can also add an induction on the length of a word $\tau$. I am pretty sure that we should use somehow the relations of the braids, maybe introducing a word between $\alpha$ and  $\sigma_{n-1}^{-1}$ and applying these relations and the induction there.

The symmetric group is generated by $2$-cycles. Can you see how that's useful here?

I see it, but I don't know how to use it.

I had originally left a comment about using the correspondence theorem (also called the fourth isomorphism theorem) to show that, since $\mathfrak{S}n=\langle S(\sigma_1),\ldots,S(\sigma{n-2})\rangle$, then $S^{-1}(\mathfrak{S}n)=\langle\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma{n-2},K\rangle$, where $K$ is the kernel of $S$ (the pure braid group). If $H=\langle\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_{n-2},\sigma_{n-1}^2\rangle$, then all that there is to prove is that $K\le H$. Now $K$ is normally generated by ${\sigma_i^2\mid 1\le i\le n-1}$. So it's enough to show these squares and all their conjugates are in $H$...

The easiest way I can see to prove that is to know about the normal form of the generators of $K$, namely that they look like $\sigma_{i-m}^{-1}\cdots\sigma_{i-1}^{-1}\sigma_i^2\sigma_{i-1}\cdots\sigma_{i-m}$. Then the fact $K$ is contained in $H$ is trivial. If you don't know these generators of $K$, then there seems to be a lot more manual work to show $K$ is in $H$, and is probably not much easier (if at all) than the proofs given below.

First, we have that $n^{S(\tau)} = n$ for all $\tau \in \{\sigma_1, \dots, \sigma_{n-2}, \sigma_{n-1}^2\}$, so these braids belong to $\mathbb{S}_n$. From here, we proceed by induction on $n$.

For $n = 1$, the group $\mathbb{S}_n$ is trivial.

For $n = 2$, we have $\mathbb{B}_2 = \langle \sigma_1 \rangle$, and on the other hand $\sigma_1^2 \in \mathbb{S}_2$ but $\sigma_1 \notin \mathbb{S}_2$, so $\mathbb{S}_2 = \langle \sigma_1^2 \rangle$.


Suppose the result is true for all $m < n$.
We now proceed with another induction on the length of $\tau \in \mathbb{S}_n$.

If $l(\tau) = 0$, the case is trivial.

If $l(\tau) = 1$, then necessarily $\tau = \sigma_i$ with $i \neq n-1$ since $\sigma_{n-1} \notin $\mathbb{S}_n$, so the result is true.


Suppose every braid $\tau \in \mathbb{S}_n$ with length less than $k_1$ can be expressed as a product of the braids $\sigma_1, \dots, \sigma_{n-2}, \sigma_{n-1}^2$.
We proceed with a third induction on $\#\sigma_{n-1}^{\pm1}(\tau)$, which we define as the number of $\sigma_{n-1}^{\pm1}$ elements in the reduced word $\tau \in \mathbb{S}_n$.

If $\#\sigma_{n-1}^{\pm1}(\tau) = 0$, then $\tau$ is a product of $\sigma_1, \ldots, \sigma_{n-2}$.

If $\#\sigma_{n-1}^{\pm1}(\tau) = 1$, then by induction on the length of $\tau$ we can assume $\tau = \sigma_{n-1}^{\pm1}$, removing other $\sigma_i$ elements if the word $\tau$ starts with them, but $\sigma_{n-1}^{\pm1} \notin \mathbb{S}_n$ and this case is a contradiction.

If $\#\sigma_{n-1}^{\pm1}(\tau) = 2$, with the same reasoning as the previous case, we can assume $\tau = \sigma_{n-1}^{\pm1} \alpha \sigma_{n-1}^{\pm1}$ where $\alpha$ is a word in which $\sigma_{n-1}$ does not appear, so $\alpha \in \mathbb{B}_{n-1}$. It is immediate to check that $\alpha \in \mathbb{S}_{n-1}$. By induction, $\alpha$ is a product of $\sigma_1, \ldots, \sigma_{n-3}, \sigma_{n-2}^2$. Since conjugation by an element is a group isomorphism, we have that $\sigma_{n-1}^{1} \alpha \sigma_{n-1}^{-1}$ is a product of:
$$\sigma_{n-1} \sigma_1 \sigma_{n-1}^{-1}, \ \ldots, \ \sigma_{n-1} \sigma_{n-3} \sigma_{n-1}^{-1}, \ \sigma_{n-1} \sigma_{n-2}^2 \sigma_{n-1}^{-1}$$
And by the relations, it is a product of $\sigma_1, \ldots, \sigma_{n-3}, \sigma_{n-2} \sigma_{n-1}^2 \sigma_{n-2}$. The case $\sigma_{n-1}^{1} \alpha \sigma_{n-1}^{-1}$ is derived from the previous one by multiplying on the right by $\sigma_{n-1}^{-2}$, and the others are obtained by considering $\tau^{-1}$. Thus, the statement holds.


With this, we assume that the statement is true for every braid $\tau \in \mathbb{S}_n$ with length less than $k_1$ or such that $\#\sigma_i^{\pm1}(\tau) < k_2$.
Let $\tau \in \mathbb{S}_n$ with length $k_1$ and $\#\sigma_i^{\pm1}(\tau) = k_2$. Since $n > 2$ and by induction on the length of $\tau$, we can assume that $\tau$ is of the form $\sigma_{n-1}^{\pm1} \alpha \sigma_{n-1}^{\pm1} \beta \sigma_{n-1}^{\pm1}$, where $\alpha$ is a word in which $\sigma_{n-1}^{\pm1}$ does not appear. We also assume that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are non-trivial, otherwise, the result is immediate.
Let $j := n^{S(\sigma_{n-1}^{\pm1} \alpha \sigma_{n-1}^{\pm1})}$.

If $j = n$ then $\sigma_{n-1}^{\pm1} \alpha \sigma_{n-1}^{\pm1} \in \mathbb{S}_n$ and $\beta \sigma_{n-1}^{\pm1} \in \mathbb{S}_n$ and their lengths are less than $k_1$, therefore they can be expressed as a product of the braids in the statement.

If $j < n$, consider the following braids:
$$\tau_1 := \sigma_{n-1}^{\pm1} \alpha \sigma_{n-1}^{\pm1} \sigma_j^{\pm1} \dots \sigma_{n-1}^{\pm1},$$
$$\tau_2 := \sigma_{n-1}^{\mp1} \sigma_j^{\mp1} \dots \sigma_{n-1}^{\mp1} \beta \sigma_{n-1}^{\pm1}.$$
It is clear that $\tau = \tau_1 \tau_2$ and that both are in $\mathbb{S}_n$. Operating in $\tau_1$ we have:
$$\tau_1 = \sigma_{n-1}^{\pm1} \alpha \sigma_j^{\pm1} \dots \sigma_{n-1}^{\pm1} \sigma_{n-2}^{\pm1} \sigma_{n-2}^{\pm1},$$
In this new expression, $\#\sigma_{n-1}^{\pm1}(\tau_1) = 2$ and we have already proved this case. On the other hand, $\#\sigma_{n-1}^{\pm1}(\tau_2) = k_2-1$ and the result follows by induction.



Here is an outline of one approach, although it's more visual than group-theoretic.
The statement amounts to the claim that any Artin braid with the property that the $n$th strand starts and ends in position $n$ is equivalent to a braid in which whenever the $n$th strand crosses to position $n-1$, it immediately crosses back. This equivalence corresponds to "pulling this strand straight". We will show that we can always perform this "pulling straight" operation.
To do this, we start by showing that if the braid has $n > 2$ strings, and the $n$th strand travels down to position 1, we can always pull it across so that it never goes beyond position 2. We will then repeat the process to pull the $n$th strand the rest of the way across the braid.
Let the braid be $\alpha_1\sigma_1^\epsilon\beta\sigma_1^{\epsilon'}\alpha_3$, where $\epsilon \in \{-1,1\}$ and the identified $\sigma_1^\epsilon$ and $\sigma_1^{\epsilon'}$ are the crossings taking strand $n$ from position 2 to position 1, and position 1 to position 2, respectively. $\beta$ has no $\sigma_1^k$ crossings.
We can distinguish two cases depending on whether $\epsilon = \epsilon'$.
In the case $\epsilon \not= \epsilon'$, we have a braid structured something like:
$\sigma_1\beta\sigma_1^{-1}$" />
So strand $n$ forms a sort of handle around $\beta$. Braid isotopy allows us to "lift" this handle over $\beta$, pushing the whole subbraid beta one place to the left:
$$\sigma_2^{-1}\ldots\sigma_{n-1}^{-1}\beta'\sigma_{n-1}^{1}\ldots\sigma_2^{1}$$ " />
$\sigma_1^{\epsilon}\beta\sigma_1^{-\epsilon} \simeq \sigma_2^{-\epsilon}\ldots\sigma_{n-1}^{-\epsilon}\beta'\sigma_{n-1}^{\epsilon}\ldots\sigma_2^{\epsilon}$ where $\beta'$ is the same as $\beta$ but with each crossing moved one place to the left.
As this is clearly a braid isotopy, this equivalence can be derived from Artin's relations. This is done for example in Artin's 1947 paper (in fact, if we just put the braid into Artin normal form, the result follows).
In the second case, when we lift the strand $n$ (starting this section in position 2) over the subbraid $\beta$, it remains entangled with the strand that exits $\beta$ from the leftmost position and crosses with it:
[$\sigma_1\beta\sigma_1$" />$\implies$$\sigma_2^{-1}\ldots\sigma_{n-1}^{-1}\beta'\sigma_{n-1}^{1}\ldots\sigma_2^{1}\sigma_1^{2}$" />
The equivalence relation is  $\sigma_1^{\epsilon}\beta\sigma_1^{-\epsilon} \simeq \sigma_2^{-\epsilon}\ldots\sigma_{n-1}^{-\epsilon}\beta'\sigma_{n-1}^{\epsilon}\ldots\sigma_2^{\epsilon}\sigma_1^{2\epsilon}$.
So we now have $\ldots \sigma_1^{2\epsilon}$ involving strand $n$. We have drawn a box around this section in the image above. We will do a "reverse handle" isotopy, pulling strand $n-2$ below this pair of crossings:
$\sigma_1^{2} \simeq \sigma_2^{1}\sigma_1^{1} \sigma_2^{2}\sigma_1^{-1}\sigma_2^{-1}$" />
$\sigma_1^{2\epsilon} \simeq \sigma_2^{\delta}\sigma_1^{\delta} \sigma_2^{2\epsilon}\sigma_1^{-\delta}\sigma_2^{-\delta}$ ($\delta = {\pm 1}$, choice is arbitrary).
Again, we can derive this equivalence from Artin's braid relations.
We will work through $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ in the same way, to obtain a braid equivalent to our initial braid, but in which strand $n$ always remains above position 2. We next repeat this process, moving strand $n$ above positions $2, 3, \ldots$ until we have obtained a braid in which strand $n$ never moves below position $n-1$. This braid is equivalent to our initial braid, but has a word in the form $\alpha_1\sigma_{n-1}^\epsilon\beta\sigma_{n-1}^{\epsilon'}\alpha_2$ where $\beta$ does not involve any crossings $\sigma_{n-1}$ or $\sigma_{n-2}$ (as such a crossing would move strand $n$ away from position $n-1$ and we have eliminated this possibility). Notice that there can no longer be any $\sigma_{n-1}$ crossings that do not involve strand $n$.
We use Artin's relation $\sigma_i\sigma_j = \sigma_j\sigma_i$ for $|j-i| > 1$ to move $\beta$ past one of the $\sigma_{n-1}$  crossings to obtain an equivalent braid $\alpha_1\sigma_{n-1}^\epsilon\sigma_{n-1}^{\epsilon'}\beta$. Now if $\epsilon \not= \epsilon'$, the two $\sigma_{n-1}$ generators will cancel out, thus we have either $\alpha_1\beta\alpha_2$ or $\alpha_1\sigma_{n-1}^{2\epsilon}\beta\alpha_2$. Repeating the process through $\alpha_1, \alpha_2$, we have the result.
====
